# multiply the result of subtracting one value from another

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to multiply:

```js
vectorDiff = placementPosition.sub(viewerPosition);
```

by 10, so that when "model" is moved:

```js
moveModel(vectorDiff, "GPS");
```

it moves 10 times more than it is currently. How do i do this; im new to javascript any help would be greatly appreciated. The following is the code block the above is located in:

```js
if ( viewerPosition !== null && placementPosition!== null) {
                vectorDiff = placementPosition.sub(viewerPosition);
                rotationSum = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(placementRotation, viewerRotation)
                //rotationSum.setY(rotationSum.y+180);
                moveModel(vectorDiff, "GPS");
                //rotateModel(rotationSum, "GPS");
```

Comment: `vectorDiff.multiplyScalar( 10 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js vectors are mutable; when you call `v1.sub(v2)`, `v1` contains the result:

```
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(2,3,4);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,3);

v1.sub(v2);
console.log(v1.toArray())
// [1, 3, 1]
```

Therefore "the result of subtracting one value from another" is just "the first vector". You need a way to multiply that vector by a single number, or *scalar*.

That method is `multiplyScalar`:

```
v1.multiplyScalar(10);
console.log(v1.toArray());
// [4, 12, 4]
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/loyuji/1/edit?js,console)

[Three.js docs for Vector3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3)

Comment: thankyou gaitat & joews I followed your advice replacing "v1" & "v2" with my respective vectors whilst adding the console logs: vectorDiff = placementPosition.sub(viewerPosition);
    console.log(placementPosition.toArray())
    placementPosition.multiplyScalar(10);
    console.log(placementPosition.toArray()); - a great learning exercise for me